# Aggregating two time series in R applying a function that needs both as input

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate

I have two time series (ts) objects `Yt` and `Yt1` that both contain daily values over five years (start = c(1, 1), end = c(5 ,365), frequency = 365). `Yt` is an original time series while `Yt1` represents a smoothed and gap-filled version of `Yt`. I want to find the Normalized Root Mean Square Error (NRMSE) between the two time series but I'd like to get one result for each of the five years. For this, I wanted to use the `aggregate()` function. But since this function only takes one input variable to aggregate, I thought I can just bind the two time series together with `ts.union` and then call `aggregate()` on a function that uses matrix subsetting.

So I have data in the form of

```
Yt <- ts(rnorm(1825), frequency=365)  # would be a seasonal signal in reality
Yt1 <- smooth(Yt)  # smoothed version of Yt
Yt_union <- ts.union(Yt1, Yt)
```

and want to apply the NRMSE function

```
nrmse_fun <- function(Yt_matrix) sqrt(mean((Yt_matrix[,1] - Yt_matrix[,2])^2, na.rm=TRUE)) / mean(Yt_matrix[,2], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Calling `aggregate()` like

```
aggregate(Yt_union, FUN=nrmse_fun)
```

I expect a result in the form of

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 5 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0.1256365 0.1091591 0.0989738 0.1071725 0.1188176
```

However, instead I get an error

```
Error in Yt_matrix[, 1]: incorrect number of dimensions
```

I know this has probably something to do with the matrix subsetting within the NRMSE function but I don't know how I could rephrase the function so that `aggregate()` has no problem with it? Using a function with two arguments also wouldn't work since I need both time series to be aggregated simultaneously. I should also mention that I need the result to still be a time series object.
I'm fairly new to R programming so I don't know if there is a simple workaround I'm missing. Maybe `aggregate()` isn't even needed here? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to create a grouping factor: `take floor(time(Yt))` as the grouping factor

Comment: @Onyambu I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. When `aggregate()` is applied to time series objects, the grouping factor is automatically set through the frequency of the time series (if you don't use other arguments). For example, in my case `aggregate(Yt_union, FUN=mean)` works perfectly and I get annual mean values as a result, all without specifying a separate grouping factor. So aggregating generally works, it just doesn't seem to work with my NRSME function.

Comment: I see. Its not possible to use aggregate n this case since aggregate works columnwise and not on a matrix

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found an easy workaround for this. If I calculate different parts of the NRMSE equation separately I can call `aggregate()` only when dealing with one time series.
This is my solution:

```
inner_term <- aggregate((Yt1 - Yt)^2, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
Yt_mean <- aggregate(Yt, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
rmse <- sqrt(inner_term)
nrmse <- rmse / Yt_mean
```

However, since this approach doesn't need simultaneous aggregation over two time series, I'm not sure if another solution exists that is more in line with my initial question. But like @Onyambu suggests, it might just not be possible to use the `aggregate()` function for matrices.